# undefined reference to qpOASES error when using dynamic library qpOASES and CMakeList.txt

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, ros2

I am building a package in ROS2. The `undefined reference to` error occurred when I want to include a dynamic library qpOASES in the header file.

The qpOASES is installed under `~`. 
I tried `find_package(qpOASES REQUIRED)`. But I got the error

```
By not providing "FindqpOASES.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "qpOASES", but CMake did not find one.
```

In the header file I use `#include <qpOASES.hpp>`. In the CMakeList.txt file I use `target_link_libraries(my_node Eigen3::Eigen ~/qpOASES-3.2.1/bin/libqpOASES.so)`. But when I compile it, The following error showed up.

```
ltv_mpc_controller.cpp:(.text+0x4a07): undefined reference to `qpOASES::SQProblem::SQProblem(int, int, qpOASES::HessianType, qpOASES::BooleanType)'
ltv_mpc_controller.cpp:(.text+0x4a7b): undefined reference to `qpOASES::QProblem::init(double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, int&, double*, double const*, double const*, qpOASES::Bounds const*, qpOASES::Constraints const*, double const*)'
ltv_mpc_controller.cpp:(.text+0x4aeb): undefined reference to `qpOASES::SQProblem::hotstart(double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, double const*, int&, double*, qpOASES::Bounds const*, qpOASES::Constraints const*)'
```

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux makefile `make_linux.mk` on line 110 there is

```
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -Wshadow -Wfloat-equal -O3 -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -fPIC -DLINUX -D__USE_LONG_INTEGERS__ -D__USE_LONG_FINTS__
```

Try removing the flags `-D__USE_LONG_INTEGERS__ -D__USE_LONG_FINTS__`

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also tweak your cmake build to add these defines.  The core problem is that the headers do not encapsulate this difference in the build settings.  The qpOASES build conveys these through `CPPFLAGS` and the defines are not exported anywhere that's externally visible.

Alternate solution:

```
    target_compile_definitions(
        my_node PRIVATE __USE_LONG_INTEGERS__ __USE_LONG_FINTS__
    )
```